# Как работать с Excel файлами .xls в Swift

Tags: xcode, excel, swift

Здравствуйте !

Понадобилось осуществить создание/редактирование файла .xls в приложении, написанном на Swift.
Google ничем не спасает. Нашел правда библиотеку LibXL, но она только для работы с C/C++ , попытки прикрутить к Swift завершились неудачей.

Рассматриваю варианты и с файлами .numbers, но тоже безуспешно.
CSV не подходит.

Думал, что с этим проблем не будет, ибо задача вроде как не уникальная.

На начальном этапе нужно хотя бы понять, как заносить значения в ячейки.

Прошу помочь кто, чем может. Благодарен любой информации.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

быстрым поиском в гугл как минимум находятся 2 варианта:
http://kvurd.com/blog/building-libxlsxwriter-for-ios/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlslib/

И еще один вариант: http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/4575/Create-Excel-Supported-XML-in-iPhone-using-Xcode.html

Comment: Спасибо. Прочитаю. Но как ?) у меня даже таких вариантов не было...

Answer (score 0):

И еще один вариант к предыдущему сообщению: 
http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/4575/Create-Excel-Supported-XML-in-iPhone-using-Xcode.html